# Why does a frame around an image leave a corner incomplete?

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

In the minimal example below, I'm trying to put a border around an image. But the bottom left corner remains blank. What does one need to do to fill it?

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

plt.figure(figsize=(152, 90), dpi=10)
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(145))
land = cartopy.feature.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'land', scale='50m')
ocean = cartopy.feature.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'ocean', scale='50m')
ax.add_feature(land, facecolor='gray')
ax.add_feature(ocean, facecolor='black')
ax.patch.set_edgecolor('red')
ax.patch.set_linewidth('1000')  # exaggerated width for example
plt.savefig('islands.png', pad_inches=10)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Example image:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default [`capstyle`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_enums_api.html#matplotlib._enums.CapStyle) of the patch (which is a `PathPatch`) is `'butt'`, set it to `'projecting'`:

```
ax.patch.set_capstyle('projecting')
```

[image]

Comment: Can't upvote yet, so...thanks!